# Double Characters while do interact() using pexpect

Tags: python, pexpect

I am using Pexpect for testing.

```
w1 = pexpect.spawn('telnet XXXX')
# or 
w1 = pxssh.pxssh()
# both with 
w1.logfile_read =sys.stdout
```

and it run fine; however if I do at some point:

```
w1.interact()
```

and then try to write something to the screen I get double characters.
for example if I type: `rmdir` it will be `rrmmddiirr`.

How can i have a single character?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`interact()` would take care of echoing for you so you need to do like this:

```
w1.logfile_read = None
w1.interact()
```

---

According to pexpect [doc](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> - `interact(escape_character='\x1d', input_filter=None, output_filter=None)`
>
>   This gives control of the child process to the interactive user (the human at the keyboard). Keystrokes are sent to the child process, and the stdout and stderr output of the child process is printed. This simply echos the child stdout and child stderr to the real stdout and it echos the real stdin to the child stdin. [...]
>
>   **If a logfile is specified**, then the data sent and received from the child process in interact mode is **duplicated to the given log.**