# Python pexpect logfile option works correctly in Jupyter Lab but not in python script

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-lab, pexpect

Environment:

- OS: macOS Monterey
- Python: 3.9.7
- Jipyterlab: 3.0.14

Code:

```
import pexpect
import sys
from getpass import getpass

selection = '0'

mypass = getpass('Enter your NT/AD user password: ')

child = pexpect.spawn ('adfs_auth --profile 123456789012')
child.expect (r'Enter your password:(.*?)')
child.sendline (mypass)

child.logfile = sys.stdout
child.expect('Pick an account from the above list:')
child.sendline (selection)
```

Behaviors:

- Jupyterlab: Works as expected
- Python script: Error `TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes`

Detailed Behaviors:

After entering my password, `pexepect` takes it over, and I get the following output on the screen as expected (`20` is just an example):

```
Starting process...
Challenge code for your Authenticator app: 20
Waiting for MFA response...
...
...
```

Once I give the correct MFA response on my phone, I get something similar to the following output on the screen.

```
You have access to 3 accounts

+----+--------------------+---------------+
| #  |  ACCOUNT ALIAS     |  ACCOUNT ID   |
+----+--------------------+---------------+
| 0  | account-0          | 123456789012  |
| 1  | account-1          | 234567890123  |
| 2  | account-2          | 345678901234  |
+----+--------------------+---------------+
Pick an account from the above list:
```

The last line of the code gives the `selection` (`= 0`) as the input and it is done.

This works as expected in Jupyterlab but getting the following error when I run as a python script:

```
/usr/local/bin/python3 "/Users/testuser/testproject/create_aws_profile.py"
Enter your NT/AD user password: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/testuser/testproject/create_aws_profile.py", line 14, in <module>
    child.expect('Pick an account from the above list:')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 343, in expect
    return self.expect_list(compiled_pattern_list,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 372, in expect_list
    return exp.expect_loop(timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/expect.py", line 169, in expect_loop
    incoming = spawn.read_nonblocking(spawn.maxread, timeout)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/pty_spawn.py", line 460, in read_nonblocking
    incoming = super(spawn, self).read_nonblocking(size)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 182, in read_nonblocking
    self._log(s, 'read')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pexpect/spawnbase.py", line 129, in _log
    self.logfile.write(s)
TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes
```

I reviewed the following two posts:

1. [pexpect.interact(): TypeError: write() argument must be str, not bytes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73149936/pexpect-interact-typeerror-write-argument-must-be-str-not-bytes)
2. [Double Characters while do interact() using pexpect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67048674/double-characters-while-do-interact-using-pexpect/67052397)

If I use `child.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer` ore `child.logfile_read = sys.stdout.buffer` everything works except the last `child.sendline (selection)` which just shows that it worked but not actually inserted the `selection` (`= 0`) into the spawned program.

If I use `child.logfile = None` or `child.logfile_read = None`, nothing is displayed on the screen after entering the password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Issue #1

According to pexpect [doc](https://pexpect.readthedocs.io/en/stable/):

> By default, `spawn` is a bytes interface: its read methods return bytes, and its *write*/*send* and *expect* methods expect bytes. If you pass the `encoding` parameter to the constructor, it will instead act as a unicode interface: strings you send will be encoded using that encoding, and bytes received will be decoded before returning them to you.

So try like this:

```
child = pexpect.spawn ('...', encoding='utf8')
child.logfile_read = sys.stdout
```

#### Issue #2

After `child.sendline(selection)` you need to wait for the spawned program to finish before exiting the whole Python script. Otherwise the spawned program may be terminated prematurely.

```
child.sendline(selection)
child.expect(pexpect.EOF)
```

Comment: Thanks @pynexj for the response. `pexpect.spawn ('...', encoding='utf8')` has the same effect as using `child.logfile = sys.stdout.buffer`.

Comment: updated the answer. see if it works for you.

Comment: yes it worked now with adding `child.expect(pexpect.EOF)` at the end. Also, having the `pexpect.spawn ('...', encoding='utf8')` also worked both with Python script and Jupyter-lab, where `sys.stdout.buffer` did work with Python script only.